# How to add a comment to a Vue SFC outside any of the root elements?

Tags: vue.js

I'm in a situation where I legally have to add a copyright notice to the top of my files and while I know how I can comment inside either `template`, `script` or `style`, I couldn't find documentation regarding how to do it outside these.

Based on the structure of the file, I assume the standard HTML comment (`<!-- Hi there! -->`) should work, and it both: a.) seems to work and b.) my syntax highlighter accepts it.

However, I'd like to be sure about it and understand how and why it works this way, I was surprised it is seemingly not covered in the Vue docs.

Comment: The syntax highlighting is a function of the Vetur VS Code extension, which parses `.vue` files as HTML, so you should use HTML comments outside the standard SFC blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you are right. There is a confirmation here: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/spec.html#src-imports

Comment: That was my thinking exactly, I became confused when I saw that VS Code highlights a `<!-- -->` comment, but doesn't recognise a `//` or `/* */`

I know it _functions_ as a JS file, but by the looks of it it kind of has three HTML root elements.